# Caesar cipher decryption for Turkish alphabet's

Tags: c++, character-encoding

I found lots of examples on the internet but couldn't find a Ceaser cipher decryption for the Turkish alphabet. Most of the letters are similar to the English alphabet but there are some differences 
Here is the Turkish alphabet:

`A B C Ç D E F G Ğ H I İ J K L M N O Ö P R S Ş T U Ü V Y Z`

`a b c ç d e f g ğ h i ı j k l m n o ö p r s ş t u ü v y z`

I found this code for the English alphabet and it doesn't have some letters like İ,Ö,Ü,Ş,ç,ğ,ı,ö,ş,ü:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char code[501];
    int shift, len, i=0, j=0;

    cout << "Caesar Cipher Decoder " << endl;
    cout << "\nThis program will decrypt the entered text using Caesar Cipher." << endl;
    cout << "\nPress any key to continue...";
    _getch();

    system("cls");
    cout << "Enter the text that has to be decrypted (max 500 characters):" << endl;
    cin.getline(code, 501);
    len = strlen(code);

    while (j < len)
    {
        if(code[j] == 32)
        {
            code[j] = code[j];
        }

        j++;
    }

    po:
    cout << "\nEnter the amount of Caseser Shift in numbers: ";
    cin >> shift;
    if ((shift > 26) || (shift < 0))
    {
        cout << "\nShift value should be less than or equal to 26. Type again." << endl;
        goto po;
    }

    while (i < len)
    {

        code[i] = tolower(code[i]);
        code[i] = code[i] - shift;

        if (code[i] + shift == 32)
        {
            code[i] = code[i] + shift;
        }

        else if(
                ((code[i] + shift > 31) && (code[i] + shift < 65)
                || ((code[i] + shift > 90) && (code[i] + shift < 97))
                || ((code[i] + shift > 122) && (code[i] + shift < 128)))
                )
                {
                    code[i] = code[i] + shift;
                }

        else if (code[i] < 97)
        {
            if (code[i] == 32 - shift)
            {
                code[i] = code[i] + shift;
            }
            else
            {
                code[i] = (code[i] + 26);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    system("cls");
    cout << "\nYour deciphered code is: \"" << code << "\"" << endl;

    cout << "\nYour text has been decrypted." << endl;
    cout << "\nPress any key to end." << endl;
    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Please help me make this work for the Turkish alphabet.

Comment: What have you tried? What don't you understand about the code you posted? Please be more specific.

Comment: since some of those characters are not part of the ascii character encoding you need to first of all use a wider data type than char. You also cannot simply add the shift value since that will result in characters that are NOT part of your alphabet

Comment: I couldnt use these letters İ,Ö,Ü,Ş,ç,ğ,ı,ö,ş,ü  when make encryp or decryp for example if I shift 1 letter "İ" with decryp I should have "I" for Turkhis alphabet but code gives "h". I dont know maybe because of its ASCII code, but I dont know how can I intagrate these letters for this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That example code you posted relies on the fact that the standard latin alphabet is a contiguous block in the ASCII table. That's not the case for the turkish alphabet, so you have to approach the problem differently.

I would recommend you to use a substitution table. Create an array of 256 characters (one for each code-point in your character encoding table) and fill each code-point with the letter which is supposed to be used instead of it. Then iterate the input text and replace each character by looking it up in that array.

Comment: I tried somethings with arrays but couldnt figure out for now. Suppose that we have "c","ç"  and with decryp how can I get "b","c" (just 1 shift c,ç  to b,c   in english order is b,c at turkısh c,ç) if it is easy can u give me a clue.

Comment: @thomas123 I'm sorry, but I don't understand your problem.